# Google Maps KMZ file not rendering in IE8 and IE7

Tags: google-maps, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, kml, kmz

I have a web app with a map in it. I've added a nice little custom map control to turn on and off different layers on the map. Currently there are only two layers, and it all works nice and fine in most browsers.

Except for IE8+7. None of the layers are showing on the map when turned on. As far as I can tell the map is loading the kmz/kml files (when preserveViewport is set to false, the map moves to the right location) but they're just not appearing. One layer contains polylines, and the other contains markers. The code I use is below:

```
function someFunction() {
    //code to initialise map etc goes here...
    var layers = [];

    //Create 1st layer
    var exchangeslayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://link.to.file/exchanges.kmz'
        suppressInfoWindows: true,
        preserveViewport: true
    });
    layers.push({name: "Exchanges", layer: exchangeslayer});

    //Code to create second layer
    var nyclayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.nyc.gov/html/dot/downloads/misc/cityracks.kml'
        suppressInfoWindows: true,
        preserveViewport: false
    });
    layers.push({name: "NY City Tracks", layer: nyclayer});

    addCustomLayerControls(layers);
}

function addCustomLayerControls(layers) {
    //there is code here that would generate the divs for the custom map control
    var container; //container is a div element created via javascript

    for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
        this.addLayerLabelToContainer(layers[i], container);
    }

    //some more code
}

function addLayerLabelToContainer(layer, container) {
    var map; //Assume I get a reference to the map

    //some code here to make pretty labels for the map controls...
    var layerLabel; // layerLabel is a div element created via javascript

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(layerLabel, 'click', function() {
        if(layer.layer.map == null) {
            layer.layer.setMap(map);
        } else {
            layer.layer.setMap(null);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Edited my original question after finding this bug is occurring with any kml/kmz file.

Comment: Does KmlLayer.getStatus() tell you anything useful?

Comment: @geocodezip getStatus() comes back with 'OK' every time, but still nothing showing up on the map.

Comment: So I just noticed that the cursor changes when I hover over the area the kml layers should be rendering. To me, this would indicate that they are added to the map, but just not visible. Is there a way to change the visibility?

Comment: Are you using "compatability view"? From [the FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#browsersupport) "* Internet Explorer's Compatibility View is not supported."

Comment: @geocodezip No I don't think so. I'm using IE9 and changing the 'Browser Mode' to IE8 or IE7.

Comment: Do you have a live version or have you tried the actual IE8 or IE7?

Comment: @geocodezip I haven't access to an actual IE8 or IE7 (hence why I'm using Browser Mode in IE9). Not sure what you mean by 'a live version'. If you mean my web app, it is running of the localhost but the kml/kmz files are coming from live servers.

Comment: If you have a public version someone (like me) that has IE8 (but not IE7 anymore) can try it.

Comment: [This](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.nyc.gov/html/dot/downloads/misc/cityracks.kml) works for me in IE8 (at least the KmlLayer does)

Comment: @geocodezip Unfortunately I can't give access to a live version then, but if I find time to put an example project together I'll leave a link here.

Comment: @geocodezip That example you gave is working in IE9 running IE8 browser mode, so whatever my problem is lies in my code. Is the geoxml3 needed to view kml files?

Comment: geoxml3 is not required to view KML files, it is a third party KML parser that I maintain.

Comment: So turns out it was a CSS problem. Img tags were given a max-width: 100%. Thanks for the help anyway @geocodezip

Comment: You didn't post any css, so there is no way we could have helped with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as it turns out my problem related to CSS. One of my stylesheets was applying `max-width: 100%` to all img tags. This was playing havok with the map markers/polylines.

Its obvious now that I see it, but when you think the problem is to do with the javascript its not so obvious. As such, I'll leave this answer here for anyone else who makes the same mistake as me.

Answer (score 0):

If you modify *addLayerLabelToContainer*() like this then it works in IE as expected. Verified it loads KMZ correctly in IE 8 and 9.

```
function addLayerLabelToContainer(layer, container) {
    // var map; //Assume I get a reference to the map
    //some code here to make pretty labels for the map controls...
    var layerLabel; // layerLabel is a div element created via javascript                       

    if(layer.layer.map == null) {               
        layer.layer.setMap(map);
    } else {
        layer.layer.setMap(null);
    }
}
```

Don't need to invoke addDomListener(). Also note the [API syntax](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#DomEvents):

```
addDomListener(instance:Object, eventName:string, handler:Function)
```

Also minor fix of syntax errors in *someFunction* as follows:

```
function someFunction() {
    // var map; //assume map is initialised, I've just removed that code
    var layers = [];

    // see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers
    //Create 1st layer
    var exchangeslayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(
    'http://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/kml/kmz/simple/big.kmz',
        { suppressInfoWindows: true, preserveViewport: true
        });
    layers.push( {name: "Exchanges", layer: exchangeslayer} );

    // ...
    addCustomLayerControls(layers); 
}
```

Comment: addLayerLabelToContainer() is used to simply add a div to the screen that when clicked will add/remove the layer. I realise now that when I was copying the code it got a little messed up. I've fixed it in my question.